# Google sheets integration with Zapier: How to create a new spreadsheet based in a model

Tags: google-sheets, zapier

My workflow is the following:

When a new document is collected by my system I create a row in a Google Sheets to make a list.

I need to create a new Google Sheets when each row is created. And that Google Sheets must follow a specific template.

I tried to do that with Zapier and that works perfectly for blank sheets, however I need to use a template, I have formulas inside. [The template is like this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vbyPvFnJ6gHWp3yan5GbpCZ8kwDLRtccnmNdESXYu0A/edit#gid=0) by the way.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

I messed around with this a little bit and I don't believe it's possible using Zapier at this time. Because of the way our integration works, we need the headers available so we can place data.

I see that there's a "Create Column" action, which you might be able to use use in conjunction with a bunch of "create row(s)" actions, but I'm not positive it would work.

Sorry I don't have better news here. ​Let me know if you've got any other questions!

Comment: Thanks for your reply David. I tried exactly that (create column+create row) however it bugged when I tried to do that and I could figure out if it would work or not.

Comment: Apart of that, the create row doesn't allow formulas and that kinda blows it